# how to run private internet access software from /user/local

Tags: 14.04, encryption, vpn

So I installed private internet access software in /user/local because it was not connecting to a server. I read that cause of encrypted home directory it wouldn't run, something to do with suid, being the reason why ive put the files in /user/local.

but now the problem I'm having is I don't know how to start the actual software from terminal so it runs.

Comment: Surely you mean `/usr/local` ?

Comment: yes i do. my bad

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it was just a typo in your question but it's `/usr/local`, not `/user/local`.

`/usr/local` is a reproduction of the same sort of hierarchy as `/usr` but separated and left empty by the system, so that anything installed there will not clash with anything installed by the system.  It's for you to add software that you compiled/created yourself or that is from third-parties.

So, `/usr/local/bin` is a place to put the executables (only), `/usr/local/lib` for libraries, `/usr/local/share` for architecture-independent supporting files, etc.  You can create your own directory structure in there if you like.

Any executables in `/usr/local/bin` should be included in your path by default and should be executable just be typing the name of the executable.  You'll need to make sure they have the execute bit set in the file permissions.